Was any UN Security Council resolution ever rejected solely by the temporary members?
The rules for any resolution state that it must be affirmed by at least 9 out of 15 members of the UN Security Council, but that any of the 5 permanent members (US, UK, France, USSR/Russia, China) can veto it.
Now, I believe most resolutions that are rejected don't have the support of all the permanent members, but I can't really find a list of all proposed and rejected resolutions.
So, has there ever been a situation where the 5 permanent members were all willing to accept a resolution, but the resolution was nonetheless rejected because not enough of the non-permanent members voted in favor of it?

Research on Drafts that Fail to be Adopted provides a specific search for "The draft resolution was not adopted having failed to obtain the required number of votes". There are 130 such resolutions to be researched to find one that fits. I'll leave that to others.

@RickSmith: I spot checked one of those, specifically this one (S2023/795). According to the agenda for that day (S/PV.9453), it was rejected in the second recorded vote of that meeting, but it both received insufficient votes and also was vetoed (by the US and UK). So your search appears to include resolutions that were vetoed, which is not what OP asked for.

@Kevin - Under the SC voting rules, S/2023/795 was not vetoed. It would have been had there been at least three more votes either In favour or Against. It is possible that other resolutions in that list may have had favorable votes by permanent members, but not enough non-permanent members "voted in favor of it". There may also be resolutions, not in that list, where no permanent member voted against, but the resolution failed to get at least nine votes In favour,

@RickSmith: That's not what the question says. The last paragraph explicitly asks for "a situation where the 5 permanent members were all willing to accept a resolution, but the resolution was nonetheless rejected." Your search includes resolutions that do not meet that criterion because one or more of the P5 voted against it. The fact that the UN happens to not count that as a veto does not change what OP asked for.

Permanent members can abstain, which would prevent a resolution from getting the required 9 votes in favour but not trigger a veto. This has happened a few times but is still outside of the scope of the question, for which I haven't been able to find an example

@Kevin - Abstention includes "willing to accept" the decision of others. The ideal answer would reference a draft resolution where the five P5 members voted In favour and the ten non-P members voted Against. However, one may be more likely to find a similar case where at least one P5 member abstained.
